# bs4 'find() takes no keyword arguments' error

Tags: beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = requests.get('https://www.amazon.sg/s?k=monitor&ref=nb_sb_noss_2').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')




product = soup.find('span', class_='a-offscreen').text
product_name = product.find('a', class_='a-link-normal a-text-normal').text

print(f'''
price: {products}
name: {product_name}

''')
```

When I executed this I got this error

```
TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments
```

I have tried changing the class, I have retyped the entire thing twice

please help

Answer (score 0):

Your second `find` is invoked on a `str` (so you're calling the builtin `str.find()` function) since you extract the text of the first span with `.text`:

```
product = soup.find('span', class_='a-offscreen').text  # <---
product_name = product.find('a', class_='a-link-normal a-text-normal').text
```